# How to properly format csv data from my sql workbench

Tags: mysql, workbench

Hello i am trying to export data from my remote database using mysql work bench.

I have been able to export successfully but the records re not properly formatted into their right columns.

Please is there any way to properly place the text in their columns,

Find below a screen shot

[image: csv file]

In the above file there are two fields insured name and registeration number.

They are jumbled together.

Is there a way i can properly format the out put

Thanks

Comment: Both the export process and import process need to have their column deliminators match. CSV is normally with commas, however tabs or \t is also common. When exporting, look at the various properties during the export process, and I'm betting you can find an option to change the character.

Comment: thanks alot it worked

Comment: sounds good. Posted it as an answer since it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it worked... I'll post it as an answer :)

Both the export process and import process need to have their column deliminators match. CSV is normally with commas, however tabs or \t is also common. When exporting, look at the various properties during the export process, and I'm betting you can find an option to change the character.